# Re-do solr query with spellchecking suggestions

Tags: solr

Using the following configuration to run the spellchecking on Solr queries:

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
  <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textTitle</str>
  <lst name="spellchecker">
    <str name="name">default</str>
    <str name="field">text</str>
    <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
    <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
    <float name="accuracy">0.7</float>
    <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
    <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
    <int name="maxInspections">10</int>
    <int name="minQueryLength">3</int>
    <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.10</float>
    <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.00001</float>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.StandardRequestHandler" default="true">
    <!-- default values for query parameters -->
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
        <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

I get the correct suggestions for bad spelled queries, however, is it possible to re-do the query again to return the results for the spellchecked terms instead of just returning the suggestions?